# Minimum of exponential random variable

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

Assume that at a bus stop, $n$ different bus lines arrive. They follow no reliable plan and the
arrival time of each bus line $X_i$
is exponentially distributed with rate $λ_i$ > 0. Note that the $X_i$ are
independent.
Answer (and prove the answer for) the following.

> $(a)$ Define a RV for the arrival time of the next bus arriving and calculate its distribution. 
> What is the rate of the next bus arriving? 
> $(b)$ What is the probability of bus line k arriving first?

$(a)$ So I define a RV as X $\sim$ Exp($\lambda$). The cumulative probability distribution $F(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$. Is this equal to the distribution of X? 
And the rate of the next bus arriving should be the minimum of X. The minimum of 2 RVs is $min=\{X_1,X_2\}$ = $1-e^{-x(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)}$. Is the minimum of all $X_i$ then $1-e^{-x\sum_i \lambda_i}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim \mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Expo}(\mu)$ are independent, then for $t>0$ we have
$$
\{X\wedge Y>t\} = \{X>t\}\cap\{Y>t\},
$$
so
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\wedge Y>t) &= \mathbb P(\{X>t\}\cap\{Y>t\})\\
&= \mathbb P(X>t)\mathbb P(Y>t)\\
&= e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\mu t}\\
&= e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t},
\end{align}
from which it follows that $X\wedge Y\sim\mathrm{Expo}(\lambda+\mu)$. By induction, if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent exponentially distributed random variables with respective parameters $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, we have
$$
Z:= \bigwedge_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathrm{Expo}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right).
$$
The distribution function of $Z$ is then
$$
F_Z(t) = 1-e^{-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)t }.
$$
The rate of the next bus arriving is $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$.

For part (b), if $X\sim \mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Expo}(\mu)$ are independent, then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X<Y) &= \int_{\{(x,y):0\leqslant x<y<\infty\}} f_{X,Y}\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_0^y \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}.
\end{align}
The event that bus $k$ arrives first is $\{X_k<Z_k^-\}$, where
$$
Z_k^- := \bigwedge_{i=1,i\ne k}^n X_i,
$$
and so the probability is
$$
\mathbb P( X_k<Z_k^-) = \frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i}.
$$